# Sonar Line Coverage not getting displayed

Tags: code-coverage, sonarqube

I am using Sonar and Jenkins to get code coverage. The build is successful but I am not getting any line coverage report on sonar. it is displaying -. Critical, Unit Test Success and rules compliance is getting updated. coverage.xml is getting generated with all the classes mentioned in it.

what could be the possible reason?

Comment: Which version of SonarQube ? which version of the SonarQube Cobertura plugin ? Are you using Maven or Ant ?

Comment: how do i check which version of SonarQube and which version of the SonarQube Cobertura plugin i am using

Comment: i checked the pom file but it is not mentioned there.

Comment: Tushar, I guess time has come to contact your SonarQube administrator.